# Erlang test cases manual fail

Tags: erlang, testcase

What is the best way to manually make a test case fail in Erlang common test?
I am using something like this:

```
ok = nok, % fail as soon as possible
```

to raise a badmatch exception and make the case fail.
I wonder if there are other (better) ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ct:fail/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ct.html#fail-1) and [`ct:fail/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ct.html#fail-2) seem to be there for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's a standard perfectly good way of doing it. An alternative would be to not just fail but to try and generate a more relevant error. For example if the function `foo_test()` returns `ok` when successful then an alternative could be to write:

```
ok = foo_test()
```

to both test and generate an error. It is still a `badmatch` error but it is easier to see what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes use the `error` function:

```
error(incorrect_foo)
```

That way I can easily distinguish different causes for failure within the same test case.  For example, I might have `error(incorrect_bar)` somewhere in the same function.